# Truffle test: How to test Ether transfer? Balance of specific account?

Tags: solidity, truffle, accounts, balances, truffle-test

How is it possible to test if my contract actually transfers money to a specific account?

```
function _transfer(address receiver_, uint256 payout) internal{
    receiver_.transfer(payout);
}
```

Testing in JavaScript Syntax. Expecting something like:

```
assert.equal(accounts[1].balance, 100 Ether);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To assert the balance of an account, try this:

```
let expectedBalance = web3.toBigNumber(web3.toWei(3, 'ether'));
let actualBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);

assert.deepEqual(actualBalance, expectedBalance, "Balance incorrect!");
```

Comment: Thanks. Especially using web3.eth is very helpful: [web3.js - Ethereum JavaScript API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html?highlight=balance#web3-js-ethereum-javascript-api)

Comment: As an update to this answer, in current versions of web3 the BigNumber functionality used in this answer is now in web3.utils as web3.utils.toBN.

[Documentation Here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#bn)

Comment: If you're using `ethers` and `hardhat`, there's a convenient function there too: `ethers.utils.formatEther(big_number_balance);`